# Generating output in a different language with org mode

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Given the following is intended to generate C++ code:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :exports both :results output code
print "struct Whatever{};"
#+END_SRC
```

The result is inserted as follows:

```
#+RESULTS:
#+BEGIN_SRC python
struct Whatever{};
#+END_SRC
```

Which is clearly not formatted as C++. How could I get it so that org generates the following:

```
#+RESULTS:
#+BEGIN_SRC c++
struct Whatever{};
#+END_SRC
```

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
#BEGIN_SRC python :exports both :results output code :wrap "SRC c++"
```

Comment: The documentation about this is now at https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html#Results-of-Evaluation

Comment: Saved my day, thanks!